# how to fetch data from woocommerce to ractnative mobile app

Tags: reactjs

guys i am starter and need to develop application for my website ,

i have json for my site for example the below link

http://catalogmasr.com/product-category/%D8%A3%D8%AF%D9%88%D8%A7%D8%AA-%D9%85%D9%86%D8%B2%D9%84%D9%8A%D9%87/%D8%AC%D9%85%D9%84%D9%87-%D8%A3%D8%AF%D9%88%D8%A7%D8%AA-%D9%85%D9%86%D8%B2%D9%84%D9%8A%D9%87/feed/json

but i dont understand what exactly to do in the docs to display the data in my app

i followed and tested my link in reactnative docs but cant reach the result

https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/network

Answer (score 0):

try using axios: https://github.com/axios/axios.
It is better and well documented then fetch which is built in react.